Which Purana discusses Radha Vallah Lal Ji?
Which Purana discusses Radha Vallah Lal Ji?

There isn't a mention of it in the Puranas as far as I'm aware. Kindly use English as per the site guidelines if possible so all users are able to read and feel inspired to post. There's a story of Atmadeva brahmana's ancestors pleasing Lord Shiva which may be treated as Sthala Purana (like in the case of many well-known temples across Bharat). https://brajrasik.org/photo/5e6f3a0f6715bf00626ed499/a-saint-in-the-inside-way-of-shri-radhavallabh-temple
